# Are generators inferior to "real" coroutines?

Tags: java, python, lua, coroutine

I'd like to know whether there's still a functional difference between what's often called a *generator* when its extended or used in a way to span multiple stack frames and coroutines as they are provided by some languages natively.

On one side I see languages like *Python* gaining features (the last being `yield from` in version 3.3) that make the implementation of most behaviors of coroutines straightforward, without providing actual coroutines. On the other side I see projects like *Kilim* and *Javaflow* that add actual coroutines to *Java*, but with some restrictions like having to annotate each method that may be on the stack when a coroutine yields with a checked exception.

While none of these projects allow a Java program to use different stacks for coroutines, which is what languages like *Lua* do to implement coroutines, they still provide all the features, I know of, that can be expected from a coroutine implementation. But this makes them very similar (in implementation) to what can be done in Python with `yield from` and the only difference that I can see is that in Python, every call site of a function that may yield must be called with `from yield` while in Java, the functions that may yield must be annotated with a checked exception without changing the statements that call the methods.

So is there actually still a difference in functionality between coroutines like they are provided in e.g. *Lua*, and what can be done using generators and `yield from` in Python or should we say that Python (and languages with similar implementations of generators) now provides coroutines?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Python generators as coroutines. I have **not** used coroutines in any other environment. Depending on your level of experience with them, this may or may not answer your question. But here's some starter code I've used that uses generators to send and receive data in a coroutine capacity, without even using Python 3's `yield from` syntax:

---

First, the routines:

```
def sleep(timer, action=None):
    ''' wait for time to elapse past a certain timer '''
    yield   # first yield cannot accept a message
    now = then = yield
    while now - then < timer:
        now = yield
    if action:
        action()
    else:
        yield "timer finished"

def buttonwait():
    ''' yields button presses '''
    yield
    yield
    while True:
        c = screen.getch()
        if c:
            yield c
        yield
```

next, the `wait` function which manages the coroutines, sending the current time and listening for data

```
def wait(processes):
    start = time.time()
    for process in processes:
        process.next()
        process.send(start)
    while True:
        now = time.time()
        for process in processes:
            value = process.send(now)
            if value:
                return value
```

last, an implementation of those:

```
def main():
    processes = []
    process.append(timer(5)
    processes.append(buttonwait())
    wait(processes)
```

I used this on a Raspberry Pi with a 2x16 LCD screen to:

- respond to button presses
- turn off the backlight after a timeout
- scroll long text
- move motors
- send serial commands

---

It's a bit complicated to get started, knowing where to put the yields and whatnot, but seems reasonably functional once it is. There are no threads and no multi-processes, so you don't gain that efficiency. But you do gain independent functions which can all access the same data as the others, all running in a round-robin fashion

Comment: Thanks for the examples, but you're not really addressing my question, which is whether there's a functional difference between e.g. Python's generators and Lua's coroutines.

Comment: You should add the Lua tag to this question if you want a specific comparison to Lua's coroutines. I *believe* there is no functional difference, but only the knowledge from a Lua developer would settle it for sure. In the meantime, my answer may help them understand Python's, and give them the knowledge to provide their comparison.

Comment: You are right, the tags `java` and `python` only mentioned languages that are on the _not quite full coroutines_ side of the argument